# How to know the version of OpenSSL my peer is using?

Tags: c, security, ssl, openssl

I have a C application.
I want to distinguish my senders based on the openssl version they are using from my recevier.
I have one with openssl 1.0.2 and the other with openssl 3.0.5.
Is there anyway I can get to know the version of the openssl my peer is using???

The client_version variable to SSL structure gives same value for both of them.

Adding this here from my comment.

So, actually My old code has some issues (which i didnt write). It does SSL_free and SSL_CTX_free before doing a SSL_shutdown. Now, this works fine in the older version of OpenSSL 1.0.2. But, Once i migrated my application to 3.0.5 I had to do SSL_shutdown for the communication to work properly. Now since I am doing SSL_shutdown i am unable to communicate with sender using 1.0.2 ssl. So, I want to know the version of ssl of sender and then do SSL_shutdown for my receiver to work properly with senders using any version of SSL. "I cant modify my old code."

Comment: Why do you think they are using OpenSSL at all? SSL is a publicly available standard with many existing implementations, OpenSSL being just one of them. `client_version` is the version of the SSL protocol, not of any library. And it is meaningless anyway, see https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/7079.

Comment: I own both sender and receiver. I know they use OpenSSL. I want to implement a backward compatibilty for the new version of my application which will be using OpenSSL 3.0. So, I want to know the version of OpenSSL the other side (sender) is using and handle my code based on that.

Comment: Then one side needs to explicitly tell the other what version it is using.

Comment: Why are you interested in the library version? You are talking a specific protocol, perhaps several versions of the protocol. All you should know is whether the other side implements the protocol, and which version if applicable.

Comment: *So, I want to know the version of OpenSSL the other side (sender) is using and handle my code based on that*  How is that going to work?  You'd have to post the version information **after** you perform the full SSL connection, and by that point the version differences won't matter at all because you'd have a secure connection.

Comment: So, actually My old code has some issues (which i didnt write). It does SSL_free and SSL_CTX_free before doing a SSL_shutdown. Now, this works fine in the older version of OpenSSL 1.0.2. But, Once i migrated my application to 3.0.5 I had to do SSL_shutdown for the communication to work properly. Now since I am doing SSL_shutdown i am unable to communicate with sender using 1.0.2 ssl. So, I want to know the version of ssl of sender and then do SSL_shutdown for my receiver to work properly with senders using any version of SSL. "I cant modify my old code."

Comment: "since I am doing SSL_shutdown i am unable to communicate with sender using 1.0.2 ssl." This doesn't sound reasonable at all. Why would that be the case? Perhaps you should ask a question about *that* problem.

Comment: By the way OpenSSL 1.0.2 is out of support since 1st January 2020 and is no longer receiving updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I own both sender and receiver. I know they use OpenSSL. I want to implement a backward compatibilty for the new version of my application which will be using OpenSSL 3.0.

Detecting the versions of the peers TLS library is is not how backward compatibility for the TLS layer should be implemented. Instead your server should expect specific TLS protocol versions and ciphers supported.

OpenSSL 1.0.2 supports up to TLS 1.2 - which is also supported by OpenSSL 3.0 (which also supports TLS 1.3). Also there is lots of overlap in supported ciphers between OpenSSL 1.0.2 and OpenSSL 3.0 - see [here for 1.0.2](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/ciphers.html) and [here for 3.0](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/ciphers.html). Note that the actual supported ciphers and protocol versions also depend on the application and maybe its configuration, but if you control both a match should be possible.

> (From a comment) So, actually My old code has some issues (which i didnt write). ... So, I want to know the version of ssl of sender and then do SSL_shutdown for my receiver to work properly with senders using any version of SSL.

Based on this your actual requirement is not to get the exact version of the TLS library, but instead only to distinguish between a client using OpenSSL 1.0.2 and one using OpenSSL 3.0, and only after the TLS handshake is done. This requirement is much simpler than actually detecting the TLS version:  With a properly configured OpenSSL 3.0 client you should be able to get TLS 1.3, while with OpenSSL 1.0.2 you can only get TLS 1.2. Getting the TLS version of an established TLS session can be done by calling [SSL_get_version](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/SSL_get_version.html).